# How to use a Seagate Backup Plus Portable harddrive on a Mac after using on a windows laptop

Tags: windows-7, mac

I have used my Seagate HD on a Windows laptop for some time now. I want to use it on a Mac now but find it difficult to set up. How can I connect it to my Mac and view all the data I have stored on it and used on a Windows laptop? Is there an easy and safe way to do this?

Comment: Give their [Backup Plus for Mac Desktop](https://www.seagate.com/support/external-hard-drives/desktop-hard-drives/backup-plus-desk-mac/) a try. I haven't used it personally, but it may help simplify the process.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to *read* an external NTFS-formatted drive via your Mac, but you can not write to it without installing something like [NTFS for Mac 15](https://www.paragon-software.com/ufsdhome/store/ntfs-mac/) from Paragon.